# Input field not reacting to data changes after being written to by a user

Tags: vue.js

While creating a Vue.js application I have become stuck at a weird problem. I want to be able to manipulate an input field (think increment and decrement buttons and erasing a zero value on focus, so the user doesn't have to) and up until a user writes to the input field, everything is fine. After that, however, further changes in the data are no longer represented in the input field.

As I was sure I could not be the only one with this particular problem, I searched extensively, but had no luck. What baffles me the most is that everything works until the field is written to, since I can not really imagine why this would remove the data binding.

The following code should show the same behavior. It is an input field component, which is initialized with a zero value. On focus the zero gets removed. This works, until a user manually writes to the field after which zero values will no longer be removed, even though the focus method fires, the if-condition is met and the data in the amount-variable is changed.

```
Vue.component('item', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            amount: 0
        }
    },
    render: function (createElement) {
        var self = this;

        return createElement('input', {
            attrs: {
                //bind data to field
                value: self.amount,
                type: 'number'
            },
            on: {
                //update data on input
                input: function (event) {
                    self.amount = event.target.value;
                },
                //remove a zero value on focus for user convenience
                focus: function (event) {
                    if (self.amount == 0 || self.amount == "0") {
                        self.amount = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `domProps` instead of `attrs` to make it reactive. But I would suggest you use vue's [template syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) or if you insist on using the render function I would also suggest you to use [JSX](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX).

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I had hoped it was an easily remediable beginner's mistake. I will wait until tomorrow before accepting as recommended, but thank you so far anyway. Thank you also for your suggestions, but as a beginner in JS working with Cordova and Vue in tandem I want to keep things as vanilla and close to the metal as possible and rather pay the price in verbosity for now.